# Scales and concentration

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, selection-principles

Let $S$ be a dominating subset of $[\mathbb{N}]^{\infty}$. Then $S=\{s_{\alpha} : \alpha<\mathfrak{d}\}$ is called a $\mathfrak{d}$-scale if for every $\alpha<\beta<\mathfrak{d}$, $s_{\beta}\nleq^{*} s_{\alpha}$.
In the paper of Tsaban, there is a lemma: every $\mathfrak{d}$-scale is $\mathfrak{d}$-concentrated on $[\mathbb{N}]^{<\infty}$.
How can we prove this lemma? It is obvious that every scale is $\mathfrak{d}$-concentrated on $[\mathbb{N}]^{<\infty}$, but every $\mathfrak{d}$-scale?

Comment: don't you want to tell us which paper you are referring to?

Comment: I forgot it sir. I am sorry, the paper is MENGER’S AND HUREWICZ’S PROBLEMS: SOLUTIONS FROM
“THE BOOK” AND REFINEMENTS
@CarloBeenakker

Answer (score 3):

There is one proof in Theorem 1.7 of the paper you cited. But a simpler argument is provided in *Products of Menger spaces: A combinatorial approach* (with P. Szewczak), Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 168 (2017). See 2.1-2.3 in this paper.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I got it. @BoazTsaban